# linux program does not answer. how can I know which routine caused that freeze?

Tags: linux, freeze, coredump

I encountered a problem with my company's server application.
I cannot kill that because I think that I won't be able to reproduce this error next time.
So I want to know how can I get maximum information about the cause of this program freeze including but not limited to the function or routine inside of it.

How to know which procedure is executing right now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can debug the process with `gdb --pid=PID` and `backtrace` will give you stack trace to find out the function.

```
--pid=PID          Attach to running process PID.
```

The example for the `sleep`

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[2] 13221
$ gdb --pid=13221
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora 7.7.1-13.fc20
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
Attaching to process 13221
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/sleep...Reading symbols from /usr/bin/sleep...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Reading symbols from /lib64/libc.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x0000003122abc970 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install coreutils-8.21-21.fc20.x86_64
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x0000003122abc970 in __nanosleep_nocancel () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000000004040cf in rpl_nanosleep ()
#2  0x0000000000403f30 in xnanosleep ()
#3  0x00000000004018ed in main ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: And that would work better if the application is compiled with debugging info (e.g. with `gcc -g`).